# Pop up dialog box with multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to javascript and jquery. And i doing one project in asp.net where i need the pop up dialog box with multiple texbox and label such as name, comments,remarks, etc.And those data should be fetched in some variables.I use simple javascript code but it worked for single textbox but doesnot support multiple.

So is there any good solution using javascript of i have to use jquery?

The code i used is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_prompt()
{
     var name=prompt("Name","");

     if(name!=null && name!="")
     {
          document.write("hello " +  name  + " How are your");
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use jquery dialog. It will be much easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with a standard javascript input box. You could easily make an HTML window pop up with multiple fields, and of course jquery is an option, but probably overkill.